# Can't insert string into listview or textbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, html-agility-pack

I am making a winform application where I can enter a player name from a game called Tibia. When I enter the player name, it goes to the website (www.tibia.com) and searches for the player, and gets me some data about the player. In this case: Returns the name, vocation and level. To do this, I am using HtmlAgilityPack which grabs the data for me from the website.

I have three string variables for this: charname, voc and lvl.

When I get the data into the variables, I can make messagboxes to print them. Like:

```
MessageBox.Show("Your name is: " + charname);
```

And that works fine.

But I can't seem to add them to my listView (called: characterList) or a textbox (textBox1). The application crashes and gives me this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

And I just cannot seem to fix it. I've done everything I can.

Here's my code:

```
//Goes to the website and grabs the data from the table
    static async Task<List<List<string>>> GetPlayers()
    {
        playername.Replace(" ", "+");
        string url = "https://secure.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=characters&name=" + playername;
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var html = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
            var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

            doc.LoadHtml(html);

            var table = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@cellpadding='4']");
            return table.Descendants("tr")
                        .Skip(1)
                        .Select(tr => tr.Descendants("td")
                        .Select(td => WebUtility.HtmlDecode(td.InnerText))
                        .ToList())
                        .ToList();
        }
    }
```

And here is my code to go through the data it found, and add it into the ListView (characterList):

```
private void addCharacter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        playername = Interaction.InputBox("Please enter a character name.", "Input Character Name");
        if (playername.Length > 0)
        {
            //get the player data from the website
            //name, vocation and level
            //add their values to the 3 variables: charname, voc and lvl.
            //and add them to the listview (characterList)
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                var players = await GetPlayers();

                foreach (var row in players)
                {
                    if (row[0] == "Name:")
                    {
                        charname = row[1];
                    }
                }

                foreach (var row in players)
                {
                    if (row[0] == "Vocation:")
                    {
                        if (row[1] == "Druid" || row[1] == "Elder Druid")
                        {
                            voc = "ED";
                        }
                        else if (row[1] == "Knight" || row[1] == "Elite Knight")
                        {
                            voc = "EK";
                        }
                        else if (row[1] == "Paladin" || row[1] == "Royal Paladin")
                        {
                            voc = "RP";
                        }
                        else if (row[1] == "Sorcerer" || row[1] == "Master Sorcerer")
                        {
                            voc = "MS";
                        }
                        else if (row[1] == "None")
                        {
                            voc = "None";
                        }
                    }
                }

                foreach (var row in players)
                {
                    if (row[0] == "Level:")
                    {
                        lvl = row[1];
                    }
                }


                if (charname.Length > 0 && lvl.Length > 0 && voc.Length > 0)
                {
                    string[] row1 = { voc, lvl };
                    characterList.Items.Add(charname).SubItems.AddRange(row1);
                }

            }).Wait();
        }
        else if (playername.Length < 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid character name.", "Error");
        }
    }
```

Here's also an illustration of the website and how it grabs the data from the tables.

[image]

So the problem is not getting the data. It gets it correctly since I can add messageboxes to print it out. But when I try add them to my listview or any textbox, it just doesn't work. It's like I can't use the data. Just print it out in messageboxes. And I don't know why.

I also tried with a button to add some custom data by myself to the listView and that works. So my way of adding the data should not be a problem. It's just that instead of inserting text directly I want to insert the variables.

Look at this example where I manually add data with a button:
[image: image2]

Comment: have you posted your code for adding data to listview or textbox ? I couldn't see it

Comment: Yes it's in the bottom of the second code-block. At the `characterList.Items.Add` I removed the add text to textbox-code though, since that was just for testing. I just want to add the strings into the listview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this line:

```
characterList.Items.Add(charname).SubItems.AddRange(row1);
```

...is executing on a worker thread; fails because non-STA worker threads are not allowed to update the UI; and thus throws an `AggregateException` because it's in a `Task`.

I'm pretty sure you don't need the `Task.Run()` in your `addCharacter_Click()`, particularly when you perform a `.Wait()` anyway.

Change it to:

```
private async void addCharacter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    playername = Interaction.InputBox("Please enter a character name.", "Input Character Name");
    if (playername.Length > 0)
    {
        //get the player data from the website
        //name, vocation and level
        //add their values to the 3 variables: charname, voc and lvl.
        //and add them to the listview (characterList)

            var players = await GetPlayers();

            foreach (var row in players)
            {
                if (row[0] == "Name:")
                {
                    charname = row[1];
                }
            }
.
. 
.
```

Note how the method above now has been marked as `async`.

Comment: When I delete the Task.Run() it gives me other errors that says I need the task.run() since it's an async. Check this image: http://i.imgur.com/aPCoz8i.png

Comment: Note that I changed the method signature to include `async` above.  i.e. `private async void addCharacter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`.  You need to include `async`.  I should have been more to the point on that sorry

Comment: @aliazik lol.  The pleasure is mine good sir.  I wish you well :)